# Creating mesh from 3-column table in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-table

I have a table with values extracted from a csv I want to make a contour plot from.
Let's use this table as an example

```matlab
tdata.x = [1;2;1;2];
tdata.y = [3;3;4;4];
tdata.z = randn(4,1);
tdata=struct2table(tdata);
>> tdata
tdata =
  4×3 table
    x    y       z   
    _    _    _______
    1    3    0.53767
    2    3     1.8339
    1    4    -2.2588
    2    4    0.86217
```

I would like to pivot this such that I can use it for plotting a contour, so in principle I want a 2x2 z matrix where rows/columns are given by y and x respectively, something in this direction:

```matlab
 x 1        2
y                                                                           
3  0.53767  1.8339
4  -2.2588  0.86217
```

where the first row are the x coordinates, the first columns is the y coordinates and in-between are the corresponding z-values. So that is to say the z-value corresponding to (x,y)=(1,4) is -2.2588.

Note, I am going to use this grid for other things down the road so solutions involving interpolation are not valid, as well the data is guaranteed to be given on a grid.

Comment: Note that contour plots, if I'm not mistaken, always imply some interpolation between points in whichever mesh you will be creating.

Comment: Mentioning the contour plot was maybe misleading, I just wanted X, Y, and Z mesh grid matrices which one could then use to make contours. I wanted the matrices themselves to only contain data because I had other uses in mind as well. I have nothing against the interpolation necessary for a contour/surf type plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unstack`, i.e.

```
t = unstack( tdata, {'z'}, {'x'} );
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Note that the column names are all prefixed with `x` because you can't have a column name beginning with a number. You should be able to extract the `x` values back again, especially if they're always integers it won't be too hard, for whatever operations you want from here...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I would use:

```
result = full(sparse(findgroups(tdata.y), findgroups(tdata.x), tdata.z));
```

Equivalently, you could use the third output of `unique` instead of `findgroups`, or `accumarray` instead of `sparse`:

```
[~, ~, ux] = unique(tdata.x);
[~, ~, uy] = unique(tdata.y);
result = accumarray([uy ux], tdata.z);
```